# How to populate against foreign keys mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
if (req.params) {
   const val = await userServices.find()
       .where({
           title: req.params.categoryName
       })
       .populate('profileId', null,
           {
               stateId: { $in: [`${req.params.stateId}`] },
               cityId: { $in: [`${req.params.cityId}`] },
           }
       );
   return res.json({
       success: true,
       val
   })
}
```

Details:
Here is the Query for populating profile details, but I want to populate inside foreign keys against `StateId` and `CityId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can do it this way actually:

```
.populate({
    path: 'profileId',
    populate: {path:'stateId'}
  })
.populate({
    path: 'profileId',
    populate: { path: 'cityId'}
});
```

Reference:[Deep Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate)